# Merging different SQL scripts into one script

Tags: sql, hive

I have 3 query scripts that are working on the same table; one is counting total number of rows, another one is counting total number of duplicated rows and the other one is counting total number of distinct (unique) rows.

To count the total number of rows:

```
select count(*) as total_rows from <table_name>
```

To count the duplicated rows:

```
select COUNT (<column_name>) as total_duplicate from <table_name> group by (<column_name>) HAVING count(<column_name>) > 1
```

To count the unique rows:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT <column_name>) as total_unique from <table_name>
```

I am trying to merge all 3 into a single script. I am able to do it for total count and unique count; But, I am not sure how to include the duplicated count query since it has a group by statement.

Any idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      sum(rows_per_col)   as total_rows
           ,count (is_dup)      as total_duplicate
           ,count(*)            as total_unique

from       (select      column_name
                       ,case when count(*) > 1 then 1 end   as is_dup
                       ,count(*)                            as rows_per_col
            
            from        table_name
            
            group by    column_name
            ) t
```

---

#### Demo

```
with table_name as (select explode(array(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5)) as column_name)

select      sum(rows_per_col)   as total_rows
           ,count (is_dup)      as total_duplicate
           ,count(*)            as total_unique

from       (select      column_name
                       ,case when count(*) > 1 then 1 end   as is_dup
                       ,count(*)                            as rows_per_col

            from        table_name

            group by    column_name
            ) t
```

---

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| total_rows | total_duplicate | total_unique |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
|         12 |               3 |            5 |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it this way:

```
select count(*) as total_rows,COUNT(DISTINCT <column_name>) as total_unique, 
    (select COUNT (<column_name>) 
     from <table_name> 
     group by (<column_name>) 
     HAVING count(<column_name>) > 1) as total_duplicate
from <table_name>
```

Comment: As written, you're going to get a "Subquery returned more than 1 value." error when there are multiple duplicates.

Comment: @BaconBits - No, not even that. At least for now, Hive does not support sub-queries in the SELECT clause

Answer (score 0):

You could union these together:

```
 select count(*) as count_total
        'total_rows' as count_type
 from <table_name>

 union

 select count (<column_name>)as count_total
        'total_duplicate' as count_type
 from <table_name>
 group by (<column_name>)
 HAVING count(<column_name>) > 1

 union

 select COUNT(DISTINCT <column_name>) as count_total
        'total_unique' as count type
 from <table_name>
```